# C: combine string and float with low memory

Tags: c, string, memory, texas-instruments

I am using a low memory MCU and need to concatenate a char* and a float. I have tried using sprintf but I believe it's too bulky, I keep getting a crash.

Specifically I am using a Tiva TM4C MCU and trying to use the graphics library to draw sensor data to the screen. I have tried:

```
char buf[100];
float i = 2.232;
sprintf(buf, "%f", i);//
GrContextFontSet(&sContext, &g_sFontCm14);
GrStringDraw(&sContext, buf, -1, 10, 30, 0);
```

What's the best way to combine these with the least amount of memory

Comment: why do you need to store the result into a char* ? would is be less memory consuming  to output it directly  ?

Comment: Sorry, I was adding new info as you commented. I am trying to use the Tivaware graphics library for a TM4C MCU.

Comment: and the crash is supposed to be generated by "too much memory" used?

Comment: @Berto99 that is the suggestion on the TI forums where users stated that sprintf is very memory heavy.

Comment: What about restricting the size of your `buf`, considering float precision it would be overkill to use 99 char to print its representation

Comment: Yes `sprintf` is memory heavy, you could also use more specialized function like [`ftoa`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/3/ftoa)

Comment: @GrantDare `need to concatenate a char* and a float` There is no concatenation in the code you posted. `I keep getting a crash` Does the crash still happen if you comment out the `sprintf` line, and replace the line above it with `char buf[100] = "2.232;"`?

Comment: you are better to init value of `buf[100]` by zero, or memset it. 
We do not make sure what in the stack in a low memory MCU.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprintf` which guarantees that will never write pass the end of the buffer

```
char your_buffer[64];
int ret_val = snprintf(your_buffer, sizeof your_buffer, "%f", your_float);

if (ret_val < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (ret_val >= sizeof buffer) {
    /* you need to resize the buffer to a bigger size
}
```